# Negative numbers falling at end of line considered as hyphenation

Tags: hyphenation

I notice that in some unfortunate situations when I am trying to write a negative number, say -10, and it happens to fall at the end of a line, `pdflatex` will end up putting the - sign on a line and moving the number 10 to the next line as if it was a hyphenation.

I can solve the problem using boxes for particular occurrences, but it becomes impractical especially with very large documents in a drafting phase. Is there a universal solution to prevent this, while maintaining regular hyphenation behavior?

Comment: Negative numbers should be typeset in math mode, to assure that the `-` character gets typeset as a (unary) mathematical minus sign rather than as a "dash". Rendering them in math mode has the happy side-effect to TeX never inserting a line break between the unary minus symbol and the associated digits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes: you should write `$-10$`, not `-10`.

Comment: You should probably also add some information about the difference in appearance of the two. In the math environment `-` becomes a `--` and I think the spacing is also a bit different.

Comment: note that as negative and positive numbers should use the same font, this means that you should  write $10$ and not 10 as well.

Comment: You can delete the last sentence: $-10$ will not break over a line.